# How to deselect a UITableView Cell when another one is selected?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to deselected a table view cell when another cell is selected. Here is the code that's just deselect the cell for second tap:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Just set multiple selection to false. `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false`

Comment: that didn't help

Comment: @Raonix if you are using the built in TableView selection method to select your cells. @Dris's answer will call the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` delegate method when ever a new cell is selected, and you can use that function to do anything you want with the cell that gets unselected.

Comment: if you are NOT using the default TableView methods to select your cells, that's a different question and you should update your question with more info regarding how you are selecting your cells.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `tableView.deselectRow()`, just simply set multipleSelection to false.

**With Storyboard**

[image]

**Programmatically**

`tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false`

Answer (score 0):

Select tableView & go to Attributes Inspector & set selection to single selection.

Programatically (inside viewDidLoad() ) you can set as:

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```